# Create a node programatically and set its CCK field values

Tags: 6, entities

I've tried the technique described here:
http://lucasforge.2bopen.org/2010/06/drupal-6-create-a-node-with-cck-fields-programmatically/

and here:
http://drupal.org/node/1111514

Neither seem to work. The node gets created, but the CCK field I'm trying to set never gets set.

Both those just describe using "field_name[0]['value'] = 'something'" but even if I set the field value through the web form and DSM the result it never has 'value' set, just '#default_value'.

I tried setting "field_name[0]['#default_value'][0]['nid'] = 'mynodeid'" but that didn't work either.

This is the structure of the CCK field I'm trying to set:

```
field_application_discipline_id (Array, 13 elements)

#type (String, 20 characters ) nodereference_select
#default_value (Array, 1 element)
#required (String, 1 characters ) 0
#columns (Array, 1 element)
#title (String, 13 characters ) Discipline ID
#description (String, 0 characters )
#delta (Integer) 0
#field_name (String, 31 characters ) field_application_discipline_id
#type_name (String, 11 characters ) application
#tree (Boolean) TRUE
#weight (String, 2 characters ) 31
#access (Boolean) TRUE
#count (Integer) 9
```

Any idea why this wouldn't be working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For nodereference fields you have to use "nid" instead of "value".

```
//123 is the nid of the node you want to reference 
$node->field_application_discipline_id[0]['nid'] = 123;
```

The best way to discover what variable to use is to install [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and view the devel tab next to the view/edit tab on the node page.

Comment: This worked! Thanks for the devel tip, I never realized what that tab was for.